# Как построить отдельные графики по уникальным значениям в таблице?

Tags: python, pandas, графика, matplotlib, анализ-данных

Есть [DataFrame](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Gj591NZb_Twl4aRPvSlG18r8yERv-6ez/view?usp=sharing) `ds_hw_grow`. Для каждого уникального `course_title` нужно построить линейный график, который будет отображать ежемесячный прирост студентов `students_grow` для своего курса на отдельном `subplot`.

Сейчас есть решение, как построить все графики курсов на одном полотне:

```
ds_hw_grow = ds_hw_grow.sort_values(["course_title", "month_start"])
ds_hw_pivot = ds_hw_grow.pivot_table(index="month_start", columns="course_title", 
    values="students_grow", aggfunc="sum")
ds_hw_pivot.plot(figsize=(16, 8), grid=True)

plt.show()
```

[image: Графики на одном полотне]

Надо вывести отдельный `subplot` для каждого курса. Все `subplot` в одном `Figure`. При этом, на всех `subplot` должны быть подписаны оси, и каждый `sublot` должен иметь заголовок по названию курса.

Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот еще вариант:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"D:\download\ds_pivot.csv", index_col=0)
df["month"] = pd.to_datetime(df["month_start"].astype(str) + "01").dt.to_period("M")
df = df.sort_values(["course_title", "month"])
df["students"] = df.groupby("course_title")["uniq_st_id"].cumsum()

n_courses = df["course_title"].nunique()
n_cols = 5
n_rows = int(np.ceil(n_courses / n_cols))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(n_rows, n_cols, figsize=(16, 8))

for ii, course in enumerate(df["course_title"].unique()):
    row, col = divmod(ii, n_cols)
    (df
     .query("month >= '2018-01' and course_title == @course")
     .set_index("month")
     ["students"]
     .plot(ax=axes[row, col], sharey=True, title=course, grid=True))
    axes[row, col].set_xlabel(None)

plt.tight_layout()
```

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Никак не могу совладать, пытаюсь развернуть `xticks`, чтобы на всех графиках были читаемы, но получается странно https://prnt.sc/tj6f95. Перечитал уйму сайтов, как не пробую, ругается или на то, что у `numpy.ndarray` нет таких атрибутов, то на `Line2D object`, с которым тоже никак нельзя.

Comment: @МихаилБойко, советую открыть новый SO вопрос об этом

Answer (score 3):

можно попробовать сделать так:

```
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True, figsize=(8, 24))
spec = gridspec.GridSpec(ncols=1, nrows=len(ds_hw_pivot.columns), figure=fig)
sn = 0

for i in ds_hw_pivot.columns:
    ax = fig.add_subplot(spec[sn, 0])
    ax.plot(ds_hw_pivot[i])    
    plt.xticks(rotation=45)
    ax.set_title(i)
    ax.grid(True)
    ax.set_xlabel("Дата")
    ax.set_ylabel("Прирост")
    sn+=1
```

Получите, соответственно, это (с параметрами сами красоту наведете, надеюсь):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, красоту наведу.