# Не могу визуализировать данные на много маленьких графиков

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, анализ-данных, визуализация

Я хочу визуализировать данные как на следующей картинке
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но когда я пытаюсь визуализировать свои данные у меня получается вот так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот мой dataframe

[dataframe](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wK2kJPAyt5EadrBA64Lx1_VggftdO87V/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Чтобы графики были отдельные надо на каждый график делать новую plt.figure либо новый subplot. Может можно и через df.plot как-то просто сделать, но я так не помню

Comment: Во-первых, ваш датафрейм не возможно скачать без запроса доступа. во-вторых: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1152190/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d0%bc-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5/1152204#1152204

Comment: Спасибо, поменял ссылку вроде сейчас должно нормально работать.

Comment: Вы уверены, что хотите построить разом 155 графиков на одном холсте? Это ресурсоемкая и длительная задача.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как я уже сказал, построение такого количества графиков на одном холсте - ресурсоемкая и небыстрая задача. Предлагаю автору вопроса пересмотреть формат вывода данных. Я же для примера пока приведу решение для первых 10-ти стран:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("df.csv", index_col=0)

fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True, figsize=(12, 50))
spec = gridspec.GridSpec(ncols=1, nrows=10, figure=fig)
sn=0
tpos = np.linspace(0, len(df.columns)-1, num=10, endpoint=True, dtype='int')
# num=10 - 10 графиков, по количеству отображаемых стран

for i in range(1, 11): # первые 10 стран (считая с 1 столбца, не включая 11-й)   
    ax = fig.add_subplot(spec[sn, 0])
    ax.plot(df.iloc[i][1:])
    ax.set_xticks(tpos)
    ax.set_xticklabels(tpos)
    ax.set_title(df.iloc[i][0])
    sn+=1
```

Результат будет выглядеть так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]